# Javascript PHP write file to server

Tags: javascript, php

I am using javascript to send data to php file on server, the php file will write the received data into a text file on server.

Javascript

```
var data = "data123";
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('POST', 'http://......../save.php', true);
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
request.send(data);
```

PHP file on server

```
<?php
$test =$_GET['data'];
$file = 'people.txt';
// Open the file to get existing content
$current = file_get_contents($file);
// Append a new person to the file
$current .= $test;
// Write the contents back to the file
file_put_contents($file, $current);
?>
```

I tried the code above, but the text file didn't change.

Comment: You are making a `POST` request but you tried to get your data with `$_GET`

Comment: You are using `POST` but in `php` you are trying to `$_GET['data']`. Replace `$_GET['data']` with `$_POST['data']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are using POST method on your ajax request, so in your php use `$_POST` instead `$_GET`

```
$test =$_POST['data'];
```

And in your javascript use `=` into your string like :

```
var data = "data=123";
```

Comment: I got 123 written into the text file. If I want a javascript variable written in the file. for example If in my javascript, I add var price =5;  , I changed  var data = "data=price"; or var data = "data=$price"; or var data = "data=var price";  but the 5 is still not written into the file. How should I change it? thanks

Comment: @Tosps Write : `var data = "data=" + price;`

Comment: possible to send 2 javascript variables separately? one is data, and one is price, I want to make if statement in php file, if data ==1 and if price <= 100, do something.   
 if data == 2, if price <= 100, do something. Thanks

Comment: @Tosps yes you can use "&" and get the two variable with $_POST, like: var data = "data=" + data + "&price=" + price;

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems.

1. You are trying to read the data from `$_GET` which contains data from the **query string** and not the request body. Use `$_POST`
2. You are claiming to encode your data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` but are actually just sending `text/plain`. You need to encode the data.

e.g.

```
var key = "data";
var encodedData = encodeURIComponent(key) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(data);

request.send(encodedData);
```

Comment: I got 123 written into the text file. If I want a javascript variable written in the file. for example If in my javascript, I add var price =5;  , I changed  var data = "data=price"; or var data = "data=$price"; or var data = "data=var price";  but the 5 is still not written into the file. How should I change it? thanks

Comment: @Tosps — `data` **is** a JavaScript variable. If you want a different variable then use that instead of `data`. Or copy its value to data. `var data = price`.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like you "post" the data or set the parameter name "data" from your javascript. If you do

```
var_dump($_POST['data'])
```

I'm quite certain you will not get 'data123';

If you post data it will reside in "**$_POST**" and if you get data it will have to be fetched from "**$_GET**". Or both are usually added to "**$_REQUEST**".

Instead, you will have to set the names like

```
var params = 'data=data123';
```

and then send your params

```
http.send(params);
```

The fetch it from the correct array depending on if you send using get or post.

Comment: I got 123 written into the text file. If I want a javascript variable written in the file. for example If in my javascript, I add var price =5;  , I changed  var data = "data=price"; or var data = "data=$price"; or var data = "data=var price";  but the 5 is still not written into the file. How should I change it? thanks

Comment: If you send the above params using post you would be able to extract if with $_POST['data'] which would contain the string 'data123'

Answer (score 0):

You have to send your data with a key

```
var data = encodeURIComponent("data123");
//...
request.send('data=' + data);
```

The PHP part should be as following:

```
<?php
$data = $_POST['data'];
$file = __DIR__ . '/people.txt'; //its not needed to add the dir
//use the FILE_APPEND flag to append your data its faster than loading the whole contents
file_put_contents($file, $data, FILE_APPEND);
```